# How to get automatically traffic dely for a route in HereMap Sdk

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am using HereMap Android Sdk.

I need to get the traffic delay for a route automatically. In [Route](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html) class i have found 3 method for calculatine Tta:

**Excluding Traffic:**

> [getTtaExcludingTraffic(int subleg)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html#getTtaExcludingTraffic-int-)
>
> Gets the estimated time to arrival without considering traffic
> conditions.

**Including Traffic:**

> [getTtaIncludingTraffic(int subleg)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html#getTtaIncludingTraffic-int-)
>
> Gets the estimated time to arrival, taking into account traffic conditions at the time of the route calculation. Note, if the route was originally calculated without setting a traffic penalty mode or originally calculated with a traffic penalty mode other than OPTIMAL, this method will return the estimated time to arrival without considering traffic conditions.

**Downloaded Traffic:**

> [getTtaUsingDownloadedTraffic(int subleg)](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/Route.html#getTtaUsingDownloadedTraffic-int-)
>
> Gets the estimated time to
> arrival with traffic conditions, where the traffic conditions are
> taken from traffic data downloaded to the device.

`getTtaIncludingTraffic` returns the `RouteTta` at the time of route calculation, which is not updated value. I can use `getTtaUsingDownloadedTraffic` but i have to manually request with `TrafficUpdater` class the retrieve the `RouteTta`.

**Is the any way I can get the delay time for traffic automatically?**

Here i have attached a screenshot from `Here WeGo` app. They show traffic delay time in Navigation screen which i have marked below.

[image: Navigation]

**How can i get the traffic delay time automatically via a callback?**

Any kind of help and suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get time duration using the following code snippet :

```
int timeInSeconds = route.getTtaExcludingTraffic(Route.WHOLE_ROUTE).getDuration();
```

Comment: This will give time to arrive without considering traffic. i have to call it manually. but i want to get the delay automatically like callback